# My Android App crashes when i run a DialogBox for the second time

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog

Hi I am just trying to make an app that will have a button that will get an input of 4 different player names from a dialog box and assign the input to separate text views.

I want it to be possible to click the button, the dialog pops up, enter name, and it will appear as player1, and then hit the same button again and enter for player2. The problem is that i cannot open the dialogbox the second time.

Code:

```
package com.example.russianroullette;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayersTab extends FragmentActivity {

    int amtPlayers = 0;//number of players currently active
    String name = "";//name input from Dialog Box

    String player1Name = "";//actual name used for player1
    String player2Name = "";//actual name used for player2
    String player3Name = "";//actual name used for player3
    String player4Name = "";//actual name used for player4

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.players_tab);

        final TextView player1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);//Player1 TextView
        final TextView player2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);//Player2 TextView
        final TextView player3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);//Player3 TextView
        final TextView player4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);//player4 TextView

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);// Set an EditText view to get user input


        final Button addPlayerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add1Button);

        player1.setText("P1: ");//updates the TextView with P1 name
        player2.setText("P2: ");//updates the TextView with P2 name
        player3.setText("P3: ");//updates the TextView with P3 name
        player4.setText("P4: ");//updates the TextView with P4 name

        //Creates AlertDialog
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Enter Player's Name");//Title of AlertDialog
        alert.setView(input);//The EditText
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Editable value = input.getText();//gets the input
                name = value.toString();//sets name as the user input from the Dialog Box

                playerId = ("Player " + amtPlayers + ": " + name);// puts all of the variables into a simple string to be used by the TextViews   
                switch(amtPlayers){
                    case 1: player1Name = (name);
                            player1.setText(player1Name);
                            break;
                    case 2: player2Name = (name);//the actual name used for player2
                            player2.setText(player2Name);
                            break;
                    case 3: player3Name = (name);//the actual name used for player3
                            player3.setText(player3Name);
                            break;
                    case 4: player4Name = (name);//the actual name used for player4
                            player4.setText(player4Name);
                            break;
                    default:    //code that asks the user which name to replace
                                break;
                }

            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
            amtPlayers--;//puts the amtPlayers back 1
            }
        });
        //Ends AlertDialog Creation

        addPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Code that adds new Player.
                amtPlayers++;
                alert.show();


            }
        });



        });
        //Code

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3225)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:401)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.example.russianroullette.PlayersTab$5.onClick(PlayersTab.java:124)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-22 19:48:58.376: E/AndroidRuntime(1284):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: I believe i have to restart the DialogBox somehow?

Answer (score 2):

create alertview in function, and make sure when you create alertview that it's a new one.

```
-(void)showAlert {
       final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Enter Player's Name");//Title of AlertDialog
        alert.setView(input);//The EditText
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Editable value = input.getText();//gets the input
                name = value.toString();//sets name as the user input from the Dialog Box

                playerId = ("Player " + amtPlayers + ": " + name);// puts all of the variables into a simple string to be used by the TextViews   
                switch(amtPlayers){
                    case 1: player1Name = (name);
                            player1.setText(player1Name);
                            break;
                    case 2: player2Name = (name);//the actual name used for player2
                            player2.setText(player2Name);
                            break;
                    case 3: player3Name = (name);//the actual name used for player3
                            player3.setText(player3Name);
                            break;
                    case 4: player4Name = (name);//the actual name used for player4
                            player4.setText(player4Name);
                            break;
                    default:    //code that asks the user which name to replace
                                break;
                }

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
            amtPlayers--;//puts the amtPlayers back 1
            }
        });
alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your EditText is already bound to the previous dialog.

One quick workaround is:
Define Context and Builder before onCreate()

```
    Context ctx;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;
```

Initialize them in onCreate():

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    ctx = this.getApplicationContext();


    final Button addPlayerButton = (Button) findViewById(...);
    alert  = new Builder(this);
    // Creates AlertDialog
            ......

}
```

Change addPlayerButton onClick to this:

```
        addPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code that adds new Player.
            showDialog();

        }
    });


protected void showDialog() {
    input = new EditText(ctx);
    alert.setView(input);
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code, please try this.

```
  public class PlayersTab extends FragmentActivity {
 private  AlertDialog.Builder alert = null;
int amtPlayers = 0;//number of players currently active
String name = "";//name input from Dialog Box
private TextView player1 ,player2,player3, player4;
String player1Name = "";//actual name used for player1
String player2Name = "";//actual name used for player2
String player3Name = "";//actual name used for player3
String player4Name = "";//actual name used for player4
 private EditText input ;
 private Button addPlayerButton;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.players_tab);

   player1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);//Player1 TextView
    player2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);//Player2 TextView
     player3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);//Player3 TextView
    player4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);//player4 TextView

    input = new EditText(this);// Set an EditText view to get user input


    addPlayerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add1Button);

    player1.setText("P1: ");//updates the TextView with P1 name
    player2.setText("P2: ");//updates the TextView with P2 name
    player3.setText("P3: ");//updates the TextView with P3 name
    player4.setText("P4: ");//updates the TextView with P4 name


    //Ends AlertDialog Creation

    addPlayerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Code that adds new Player.
             amtPlayers++;

             //You should create dialog after you click, in your earlier code, it was always there.
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter Player's Name");//Title of AlertDialog
    alert.setView(input);//The EditText
    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Editable value = input.getText();//gets the input
            name = value.toString();//sets name as the user input from the Dialog Box

            playerId = ("Player " + amtPlayers + ": " + name);// puts all of the variables into a simple string to be used by the TextViews   
            switch(amtPlayers){
                case 1: player1Name = (name);
                        player1.setText(player1Name);
                        break;
                case 2: player2Name = (name);//the actual name used for player2
                        player2.setText(player2Name);
                        break;
                case 3: player3Name = (name);//the actual name used for player3
                        player3.setText(player3Name);
                        break;
                case 4: player4Name = (name);//the actual name used for player4
                        player4.setText(player4Name);
                        break;
                default:    //code that asks the user which name to replace
                            break;
            }

        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
        amtPlayers--;//puts the amtPlayers back 1
        }
    });  
      alert.show();
        }
    });
```

I would still suggest you to go with [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html), it is the right way to work with all types of Dialogs.

For examples you can refer to this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html).